# Cannot find eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can I find eigenvectors of the following matrix?

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        4 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Systematic approach would be: 1. Finding eigenvalues (4,1), 2. solve

`(A-4I)x = 0` and `(A-1I)x = 0`.

For some reason I am unable to solve augmented matrices:

For eigenvalue 4:$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 0\\  
        0 & -3 & 0\\
        \end{matrix} 
$$

and

For eigenvalue 1:$$
        \begin{matrix}
        3 & 0 & 0\\  
        0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{matrix} 
$$

How can I get eigenvectors (1,0) and (0,1) from those matrices?

Answer (score 2):

For the first eigenvalue, $\lambda_1 = 4$, we form $[A-4I]v_1=0$ and we have a RREF of:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_1 = 0 \implies v_1 = (1,0)$$

For the second eigenvalue, $\lambda_2 = 1$, we form $[A-1I]v_2=0$ and we have a RREF of:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_2 = 0 \implies v_2 = (0,1)$$

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. My brain blocked for some reason.